# Is there a way to signify an ignored/throwaway/wildcard value in ES2015?

Tags: ecmascript-6

What I'm looking for is a is something like the **underscore** on line 5:

```
const returnValues = () => {
  const foo = {'one': 1}
  const bar = {'two': 2}

  return { 
    foo, bar
  }
}

const { _, valueToBeUsed } = returnValues();

//do things with valueToBeUsed
```

It'd be nice and clean to have a way to signify that I don't need the first variable.

Some pattern-matching languages like Swift and Haskell call this a *wildcard pattern*.

Comment: This is invalid syntax. Did you mean to use array destructuring?

Comment: 1 and 2 should be objects themselves. I wasn't thinking when I created the example. Updated the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `returnValues` function contains invalid syntax. If you meant to use array destructuring here, you can treat the array as an Object instead:

```
const returnValues = () => {
  return [ 1, 2 ];
}

const { 1: valueToBeUsed } = returnValues();
console.log(valueToBeUsed); // 2
```

If `returnValues` should return an object, you do not need to destructure unused properties at all:

```
const returnValues = () => {
  return { one: 1, two: 2 };
}

const { two: valueToBeUsed } = returnValues();
console.log(valueToBeUsed); // 2
```

Comment: The second case is the answer I was looking for, thanks.